# Complete or Extend Orthonormal Basis in Python

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I have a couple of orthonormal vectors. I would like to extend this 2-dimensional basis to a larger one. What is the fastest way of doing this in Python with NumPy?

My thoughts were the following: Generate a random vector of the required size (new_dimension > 2), perform Gram-Schmidt by substracting scaled dot-products with the previous two. Repeat. I doubt that this is the quickest way though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify the dimension of your space. **If it is 3**, then you can simply use the [cross product](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cross.html) of your two vectors. If it is not, then see below.

### Example in 3-D

```py
# 1. setup: an orthonormal basis of two vectors a, b
np.random.seed(0)
a, b = np.random.uniform(size=(2,3))
a /= np.linalg.norm(a)
b -= a.dot(b)*a
b /= np.linalg.norm(b)

# 2. check:
>>> np.allclose([1,1,0,0], [a.dot(a), b.dot(b), a.dot(b), b.dot(a)])
True
```

Then, making a new vector:

```py
# 3. solve
c = np.cross(a, b)

# 4. checks
>>> np.allclose([1,0,0], [c.dot(c), c.dot(a), c.dot(b)])
True
```

If the dimension of your vectors is higher, then you can pick any vector that is not in the plane defined by `a,b` and subtract that projection, the normalize.

### Example in higher dimensions

```py
# 1. setup
n = 5
np.random.seed(0)
a, b = np.random.uniform(size=(2, n))
a /= np.linalg.norm(a)
b -= a.dot(b)*a
b /= np.linalg.norm(b)

# 2. check
assert np.allclose([1,1,0,0], [a.dot(a), b.dot(b), a.dot(b), b.dot(a)])
```

Then:

```py
# 3. solve
ab = np.c_[a, b]
c = np.roll(a + b, 1)  # any vector unlikely to be 0 or some
                       # linear combination of a and b
c -= (c @ ab) @ ab.T
c /= np.linalg.norm(c)

# 4. check
abc = np.c_[a, b, c]
>>> np.allclose(np.eye(3), abc.T @ abc)
True
```

### Generalization: complement an `m`-basis in a `n`-D space

In an `n`-dimensional space, given an `(n, m)` orthonormal basis `x` with `m` s.t. `1 <= m < n` (in other words, `m` vectors in a `n`-dimensional space put together as columns of `x`): find `n - m` vectors that are orthonormal, and that are all orthogonal to `x`.

We can do this in one shot using [SVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Geometric_meaning).

```py
# 1. setup
#    we use SVD for the setup as well, for convenience,
#    but it's not necessary at all. It is sufficient that
#    x.T @ x == I

n, m = 6, 2  # for example
x, _, _ = np.linalg.svd(np.random.uniform(size=(n, m)))
x = x[:, :m]

# 2. check
>>> np.allclose(x.T @ x, np.eye(m))
True

>>> x.shape
(6, 2)
```

So, at this point, `x` is orthonormal and of shape `(n, m)`.

Find `y` to be one (of possibly many) orthonormal basis that is orthogonal to `x`:

```py
# 3. solve
u, s, v = np.linalg.svd(x)
y = u[:, m:]

# 4. check
>>> np.allclose(y.T @ y, np.eye(n-m))
True

>>> np.allclose(x.T @ y, 0)
True
```

Comment: Sure, but how do you extend this to higher dimensions? I.e. An orthogonal R^n basis for generic n

Comment: see extended answer for `n > 3`.

Comment: there was an issue with the previous version (where `c` could be 0 for e.g. `a = I[i]` and `b = I[j]`).

Comment: I also added an extension to fully complement an _m_-basis in _n_-dimensions (given _m_ orthonormal vectors, find _n-m_ new vectors orthogonal to each other and to each of the first _m_ ones.